# Regex expression to scrape info from the middle of a string

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I am building a web scraper using webscraper.io. One string I am scraping is the following one:

> Best Sellers Rank: #597 in Books (See Top 100 in Books) #1 in Feng
> Shui (Books) #2 in Zen Philosophy (Books) #7 in Home Cleaning,
> Caretaking & Relocating

I am trying to create a regex expression that would isolate from the above string just the first number (`597`). The expression should be able to extract any format of this number, whether it's just a simple `597` or something with a comma separator for thousands and millions (e.g. `1,300` or `10,000,000`).

I tried to use something with lookbehind but it seems like webscraper.io or Chrome do not like this and return a "null" result.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are your constraints here?  You haven't described what you do and don't want to match, and you haven't posted what you've already tried.  I don't understand why you would need a lookbehind here.  What's wrong with simply using `[\d,]+`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it's probably going to be a lot of effort for you if you're using `regex` to web scrape. I would recommend using a library like `BeautifulSoup` if you're using Python, or some other web scraping library if you're using another language.

Comment: You should also add what language you're using

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*
```

which means:

- `\d{1,3}` = between 1 & 3 digits
- `(,\d{3}*` = a comma then 3 digits, zero or more times